# How tabButton can switch pages in QML (Qt Quick)

Tags: python, qt, qml, qtquick2

Want to design my app something like that:
[image]

Please focus on tabButtons, When click on tabButton1 the page_1 is in rectangle_2, when click tabButton2 the page_2 is in rectangle 2. I am not able to do it. Can anyone help me please?

There is functional code - not working like I want

main.py

```
    import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

main.qml

```
    import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls 6.3
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 960
    height: 540
    visible: true

        Rectangle {
            id: appPlace
            color: "#10021f"
            anchors.fill: parent

            Rectangle {
            id: topBar
            height: 70
            color: "#1f504f"
           
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0

            Text {
            id: text1
            height: 55
            text: qsTr("TopBar ")
            color: "#ffffff" 
            } 
        }
       
    }

    footer: TabBar {
            id: tabBar
            currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
            Material.background:  "#003B5C"
            width: parent.width
          
            TabButton {
                font.bold: true
                font.pointSize: 14
                text: qsTr("App")
            }
            TabButton {
                font.bold: true
                font.pointSize: 14
                text: qsTr("Settings")
            }
        }
    
     StackLayout {
         anchors.fill: parent
         currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
        
         Item{
             id: page1
              Rectangle{
                id: w1
                 anchors.left: parent.left
                 anchors.top: topBar.bottom
                 anchors.topMargin: 0
                 anchors.leftMargin: 0
                 //anchors.fill: parent
                 color: 'red'

            }
          }

          Item {
              id: page2
               Rectangle{
                  id: w2
                  anchors.left: parent.left
                  anchors.top: topBar.bottom
                  anchors.topMargin: 0
                  anchors.leftMargin: 0
                  //anchors.fill: parent
                  color: 'blue'
               }
          }

     }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your TabBar was already working. The only problem is your Rectangles have no size so you couldn't see them. Give them a width and a height and they will work just fine. Your anchors are also wrong because you cannot anchor w1 to topBar. You should see an error on the console about that. You can only anchor to objects that are direct parents or siblings.

```
StackLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.topMargin: topBar.height  // Don't cover up the topBar
    currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
    
    Item {
        id: page1
        Rectangle {
            id: w1
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
        
    Item {
        id: page2
        Rectangle {
            id: w2
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: 'blue'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed it as you said. Now the tabButtons work, but topBar disappears.

Comment: The topBar doesn't get covered if you use the anchoring on the StackLayout like I showed you.

Comment: You are right, I totally overlooked it, Thank you!

Comment: Since you are already using `footer` for your TabBar, you could have used `header` for your topBar. Had you done that your StackLayout would be simply `anchors.fill: parent`.

Answer (score 0):

OK now it works, Just add anchor to StackLayout: Whole Qml solution here:

```
ApplicationWindow {
width: 960
height: 540
visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: appPlace
        color: "#10021f"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
        id: topBar
        height: 70
        color: "#1f504f"
       
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.topMargin: 0

        Text {
        id: text1
        height: 55
        text: qsTr("TopBar ")
        color: "#ffffff" 
        } 
    }
   
}

footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
        Material.background:  "#003B5C"
        width: parent.width
      
        TabButton {
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 14
            text: qsTr("App")
        }
        TabButton {
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 14
            text: qsTr("Settings")
        }
    }

 StackLayout {
     anchors.fill: parent
     currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
     anchors.top: parent.top
     anchors.topMargin: 70
    
     Item{
         id: page1
          Rectangle{
            id: w1
            width: 200
            height: 200
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: 'red'
        }
      }

      Item {
          id: page2
           Rectangle{
              id: w2
              
            width: 200
            height: 200
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: 'blue'
           }
      }
 }
```

}